# NGram analyzer with approx length match

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, n-gram

I have ngram custom analyzer having mingram and maxgram as 3. I am getting results but i want to add length analyzer. It should first display results having length match with supplied string length.

ex. I am searching for abcxyz

Current result: abcxyzabcxyzabcxyzabcxyzabcxyz, abcxyzabcxyz

Expected :abcxyzabcxyz should come first before abcxyzabcxyzabcxyzabcxyzabcxyz

Comment: can you share the custom analyzer settings that you have used so that i can debug it.

Comment: why do you expect `abcxyzabcxyz` to come before `abcxyzabcxyzabcxyzabcxyzabcxyz` with the analysis configuration you have?

Comment: @Yatin length of first one is approximately near to the provided word

Comment: @AmolHegana relevancy scoring operates on tokens in the inverted index, which are a product of analysis. With an analyzer that generates trigrams from the input, there will be more matching tokens for the longer `abc...` input than the shorter. A way to understand how a score is calculated is to use the explain API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-explain.html

Comment: @Russ cam I am got your point but I wanted to  redefine scoring logic. Right now it identifies based on tokens present in matching string. I want to include relative length of both strings and use as scoring factor.